# Facebook Swift SDK: loginManager Type of expression is ambiguous error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoa-touch, sdk

I'm using the following code to add a facebook login to a UIButton action:

```
func facebookButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController : self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
            case .Failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .Cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login")
            case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in")
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode is throwing the following error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

for the `[.PublicProfile]` part.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Having the same issue. Look forward to seeing a response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The final solution is this one:

```
 let loginManager=LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ReadPermission.publicProfile], viewController : self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in")
        }
    }
```

Facebook hasn't updated its own codes' examples...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since as of today, none of the above examples work. Even if they do, its due to some weird syntax. Also, as noted, Facebook hasn't updated their docs to reflect this change.

Answer (score 10):

Try this for latest SDK

```
func facebookButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController : self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .Failed changed to .failed & similar

Answer (score 8):

You should add readPermissons: before the first parameter:

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

i recently resolved this error.

replace .publicProfile with ReadPermission.publicProfile

this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I somewhat fixed this issue by using the proper facebook syntax since the recent update.

> ```
> @IBAction func facebookBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
> ```

```
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
viewController: self
```

to

```
viewController: nil
```

solved this issue for me

Comment: Strangely this solved it for me to. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @objc func loginButtonClicked(sender : UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController : self) { loginResult in
      switch loginResult {
      case .failed(let error):
        print(error)
      case .cancelled:
        print("User cancelled login")
      case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
        print("Logged in")
      }
    }
      }
```

Comment: Code-only answers generally get downvoted. It would be beneficial to anyone wanting to use your solution to [edit] and provide some context around your code to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

If you want more permissions use this code.

```
@IBAction func onClickFBSign(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let loginManager=LoginManager()
    //Here in this line you need to mention permissions like .email, .userFriends, .userBirthday etc..
    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ReadPermission.publicProfile, .email, .userFriends, .userBirthday], viewController : self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in : \(grantedPermissions), \(declinedPermissions), \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login